# Sorting 'human' numbers in tablesorter

Tags: javascript, sorting, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter to sort a set of values whose formats vary from things like `710,231` to `6.39 million`, `37.3 million`, `5.3 million`, and so forth. Currently, the plugin sorts simply ignores the `million` and otherwise sorts fine, but consequently you get something like `5.3 million, 6.39 million, 37.3 million, 710,231,

Comment: If tablesorter is a particular plugin or library you should be more specific, and probably make it a link to the documentation.  Further, please ask a question.  If you don't ask a question you can't get an answer.

Comment: In other words, the tablesorter is working exactly right, it's the data that is messy.

Comment: Based on what you have said, it's probably just using *parseFloat*. You first need a function that will convert the "human" numbers to real numbers (e.g. 6.3 million to 6300000), then you can sort them as you wish.

Comment: I should specify that, in this case, the numbers do still need to need to display as "human" numbers to the end user... (They do, in fact, exist as real numbers in the underlying data, but are being converted to 'human' figures for anything above 999,999)

Comment: Then sort the raw values before converting to "human" versions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a parser to replace the names with their value ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4230/)):

```
// see big list here: http://www.unc.edu/~rowlett/units/large.html
var numbers = {
    'zero'        : 0,
    'hundred'     : 100,
    'thousand'    : 1e3,
    'million'     : 1e6,
    'billion'     : 1e9,
    'trillion'    : 1e12,
    'quadrillion' : 1e15,
    'quintillion' : 1e18,
    'sextillion'  : 1e21,
    'septillion'  : 1e24,
    'octillion'   : 1e27,
    'nonillion'   : 1e30,
    'decillion'   : 1e33
};

$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "namedNumbers",
    is: function () {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table) {
        var v,
            result = 1,
            arry = (s || '').split(/[\-\s]+/),
            len = arry.length;
        while (len) {
            v = $.tablesorter.formatFloat( (arry[--len] || '').toLowerCase(), table );
            if ( numbers.hasOwnProperty(v) ) {
                result *= numbers[v];
            } else {
                result *= parseFloat(v);
            }
        }
        return result !== 1 ? result : s;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});

$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headers : {
            1 : { sorter : 'namedNumbers' }
        }
    });
});
```